# How should I change encryption according to *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used

Tags: encryption, openssl

When I encrypt or decrypt a file I get:

> *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
> Using `-iter` or `-pbkdf2` would be better.

---

I do not understand what this means, and how I should change my procedure.

Thus far, I encrypted with:

```
openssl des3 <input >output.des3
```

and decrypt with:

```
openssl des3 -d <input.des3 >output
```

---

OS: Ubuntu 18.10

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

Comment: 3DES as an encryption method is being retired.   The warning is just suggesting you use another method, maybe refer to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51629/is-triple-des-still-considered-safe-to-use for more details.

Comment: That error happens for any kind of ciphers. 
You need to add -pbkdf2 to both encrypt and decrypt commands.

Comment: Sorry, but could you please give an example of how to add -pbkdf2 to the commands? I don't understand how it should be added.

Comment: In your example, you just need to do `openssl des3 -e -pbkdf2 < input  > output.des3` and `openssl des3 -d -pbkdf2 < input.des3 > output`. I also happen to agree with the first comment that you should use a different block cipher instead of 3DES (DES is from 1977), an easy way to do that is just to swap in `aes256` where you currently have `des3` in those commands, to use AES (256-bit AES meets current security standards).

Comment: Thanks! Now it works and without warnings using aes256. So the question is answered.

Comment: What gets me is they added a nice option, but then do not tell you what the default iteration count is, or how to make proper use of it!

Answer (score 39):

Comparing the Synopsys of the two main and recent versions of OpenSSL, let me quote the man pages.

### [OpenSSL **1.1.0**](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man1/openssl-enc.html)

> ```
> openssl enc -ciphername [-help] [-ciphers] [-in filename] [-out filename] [-pass arg] [-e] [-d] [-a/-base64] [-A] [-k password] [-kfile filename] [-K key] [-iv IV] [-S salt] [-salt] [-nosalt] [-z] [-md digest] [-p] [-P] [-bufsize number] [-nopad] [-debug] [-none] [-engine id]
> ```

### [OpenSSL **1.1.1**](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-enc.html)

> ```
> openssl enc -cipher [-help] [-ciphers] [-in filename] [-out filename] [-pass arg] [-e] [-d] [-a] [-base64] [-A] [-k password] [-kfile filename] [-K key] [-iv IV] [-S salt] [-salt] [-nosalt] [-z] [-md digest] [-iter count] [-pbkdf2] [-p] [-P] [-bufsize number] [-nopad] [-debug] [-none] [-rand file...] [-writerand file] [-engine id]
> ```

---

There obviously are some greater differences, namely considering this question, there are these two switches missing in the 1.1.0:

- `pbkdf2`
- `iter`

---

You have basically two options now. Either ignore the warning or adjust your encryption command to something like:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000000 -salt -in InputFilePath -out OutputFilePath
```

Where these switches:

- `-aes-256-cbc` is what you *should* use for maximum protection or the 128-bit version; <sub>the 3DES (Triple DES) got abandoned some time ago, see [Triple DES has been deprecated by NIST in 2017](https://csrc.nist.gov/News/2017/Update-to-Current-Use-and-Deprecation-of-TDEA)</sub>, while AES gets accelerated by all modern CPUs by a lot; you can simply verify if your CPU has the [AES-NI instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set) for example using `grep aes /proc/cpuinfo`; *win, win*
- `-md sha512` [is a bit the faster variant of SHA-2 functions family compared to SHA-256](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52646/42045) while it might be a bit more secure; *win, win*, but that likely changes with the new [SHA instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_SHA_extensions) in modern CPUs
- `-pbkdf2`: use [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2) algorithm
- `-iter 1000000` is overriding the default count of iterations (which is 10000) for the password, quoting the man page:

  > Use a given number of iterations on the password in deriving the encryption key. High values increase the time required to brute-force the resulting file. This option enables the use of PBKDF2 algorithm to derive the key.

---

The default value of iterations is not documented, but specified in `apps/enc.c` file like this:

```c
case OPT_PBKDF2:
    pbkdf2 = 1;
    if (iter == 0)
        iter = 10000;
    break;
```

---

Decryption is issued simply by adding `-d` switch to the end of the original command-line.

Comment: These commands were helpful for me: `openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -e -in plaintext.txt -out encrypted.txt` and `openssl enc -base64 -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 100000 -d -in encrypted.txt -out decrypted.txt`. But I'm worried about vulnerabilities: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16056298/470749

Answer (score 6):

The other answer is essentially correct. though other things have changed around these versions (v1.1.0 and v1.1.1) that is good to be aware of.

First the default password hashing digest has changed, going from md5 to sha512

And second the addition the "-pbkdf2" "-iter" which has been needed for a long time.  However the default iteration count is far too low, and should be set as high as possible without becoming too annoying.  Big enough to take 1 to 2 seconds is generally acceptable for both encrypting and decrypting, but makes it very very difficult for brute forced password guessing.

The problem is now we have all these new options and defaults,  as well as different digests and cyphers, you need to remember all these options do you can decrypt the encrypted file.   That is whatever options was decided on to encrypt must be used to decrypt.  However openssl only stores some 'file magic' (EG "Salted__" at the start of the file), and the random "salt" that was used, with the encrypted file.   It leaves it up to you to remember everything else!

Aespipe is a old program that got around this by saving some of this information as a extra header to the encrypted data, but it is now becomming dated, and its format does not allow for the new options, or for easy expansion.

As a alternative I have been creating a new script "keepout" as a wrapper around "openssl enc" to save those extra options that is needed to remember how to decrypt that specific file, even as newer options, cyphers, or larger iterations are used when encrypting.   Basically it saves the openssl option needed with the data.

https://antofthy.gitlab.io/software/#keepout