# Warning: deprecated key derivation used

Tags: encryption, openssl

This was given to decrypt a file but it is not working:
`openssl des3 -d -salt -in file.des3 -out file.txt -k supersecretpassword123`

```
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
140239690076800:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:599:
```

I have tried the answer given at [How should I change encryption according to *** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093591/how-should-i-change-encryption-according-to-warning-deprecated-key-derivat) but this doesn't work.

Comment: Hello. I do not understand the issue. This was given do you mean this is the command you used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the thing I think you are, the solution I found was to try and do this step using their web shell. I believe it is a openssl version issue, but I don't exactly know which problem. I had also messed around with trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39637388/encryption-decryption-doesnt-work-well-between-two-different-openssl-versions/39641378#39641378) but it didn't fix it. The web shell appears to be on openssl 1.1.1f and does work.